MSAGL - how to copy node preserving text color
I want to copy some nodes from a graph to another. Everything I need is copied with the following function:
MNode copyNode(MNode other) {
    return new MNode(other.Id) {
        LabelText = other.LabelText,
        Attr = new() {
            Color = other.Attr.Color,
            FillColor = other.Attr.FillColor,
            LineWidth = other.Attr.LineWidth,
        },
        Id = other.Id,
        UserData = other.UserData,
    };
}

But when I want to copy color of the text, it doesn't work. I tried to copy the whole Label (Label = other.Label) object and tried to copy member-wise - the new graph shows nodes (sizes adjusted to text) without text inside. It disappears.
MNode copyNode(MNode other) {
    return new MNode(other.Id) {
        LabelText = other.LabelText,
        Attr = new() {
            Color = other.Attr.Color,
            FillColor = other.Attr.FillColor,
            LineWidth = other.Attr.LineWidth,
        },
        Id = other.Id,
        UserData = other.UserData,
        Label = new() {
            FontColor = other.Label.FontColor,
            Text = other.Label.Text,
        },                
    };
}

That's how I create nodes (g is Graph). When they are created here, labels have colors as assigned:
var node = g.AddNode(vec.vecIdx.ToString());
node.Label.FontColor = node.Attr.Color = getNodeColor(vec);
if (v9Core.preservedStm.Take(5).Contains(vec))
    node.Attr.FillColor = Color.Gray;
else if (v9Core.preservedStm.Skip(5).Contains(vec))
    node.Attr.FillColor = Color.LightGray;
node.LabelText = getLabel(vec);
gViewer.Graph = g;

This is how I use copyNode:
 var nodes = gViewer.Graph.Nodes.Where(n => n.IsVisible).Select(n => copyNode(n)).ToHashSet();
 var g = new Graph();
 nodes.ForEach(n => g.AddNode(n));

